# Understanding Bash changes in Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: command-line, bash

I have seen a few questions that people have posted regarding Bash returning different results

For example, a message given when using the exit command. 
I have noticed that a `[` is added to previous command line prompts when a new prompt appears like this `[$`.

Also a key graphic appears when a password entry is required.

I’m curious as to what has changed to Bash and/or the Terminal in the Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) release.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it’s not `bash` specific. Terminal appears to insert these so called ‘Marks’ in any shell, but it can be disabled via the menu “Edit → Marks → Automatically Mark Prompt Lines”.

The password prompt could be Terminal interacting with `sudo`, scanning for the sequence that prompts for the password and replacing the usual empty space with a custom key symbol. I can’t find any toggle for this though.